# Do the Gnostic Gospels exist online anywhere in original Coptic?

Tags: reference-request, coptic

I have seem *images* and *pdfs* of the [Gnostic Gospels online](http://www.gnosis.org/library.html), but nothing in plain text (copy-pastable) Coptic. Does such a thing exist? I would like to read the original Coptic scripts in full, and make notes and snippets from the original Coptic.

Answer (score 1):

Some of these texts are PDFs, but the text is selectable. For example:

http://gospel-thomas.net/gtbypage_112702.pdf

To render the Coptic text, you will need to install a Coptic font:

https://www.copticchurch.net/coptic_fonts/